# How to ensure that test is executed after all tests in scalatest?

Tags: scalatest

I want to test that all methods of a REST API are covered by tests. 
All http calls are recorded into a mutable set, and I have a piece of code that checks correspondence between specification and the result set of recored api calls.

I can place this check in a separate `test` at the end of FunSuite and it would be executed after all other tests. However, there are two problems: I have to copy-paste it in every file that tests API and make sure it is at the end of file.

Using common trait does not work: tests from parent class are executed before tests from child class. Placing the test inside `afterAll` does not work either: `scalatest` swallows all exceptions (including test failures) thrown in it.

Is there a way to run some test after all others without boilerplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would go with dedicated coverage tool such as [scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage). One advantage would be avoiding global state.

Nevertheless, as per question, a way to execute test after all tests would be via [`Suites`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.8/org/scalatest/Suites.html) and `BeforeAndAfterAll` traits like so

```
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Suites, Matchers}

class AllSuites extends Suites(
  new FooSpec,
  new BarSpec,
) with BeforeAndAfterAll withy Matchers {

  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    // matchers here as usual
  }
}
```

Here is a toy example with global state as per question

*AllSuites.scala*

```
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Matchers, Suites}

object GlobalMutableState {
  val set = scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int]()
}

class AllSuites extends Suites(
  new HelloSpec,
  new GoodbyeSpec
) with BeforeAndAfterAll with Matchers {

  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    GlobalMutableState.set should contain theSameElementsAs Set(3,2)
  }
}
```

*HelloSpec.scala*

```
@DoNotDiscover
class HelloSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "The Hello object" should "say hello" in {
    GlobalMutableState.set.add(1)
    "hello" shouldEqual "hello"
  }
}
```

*GoodbyeSpec.scala*

```
@DoNotDiscover
class GoodbyeSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "The Goodbye object" should "say goodbye" in {
    GlobalMutableState.set.add(2)
    "goodbye" shouldEqual "goodbye"
  }
}
```

Now executing `sbt test` gives something like

```
[info] example.AllSuites *** ABORTED ***
[info]   HashSet(1, 2) did not contain the same elements as Set(3, 2) (AllSuites.scala:15)
[info] HelloSpec:
[info] The Hello object
[info] - should say hello
[info] GoodbyeSpec:
[info] The Goodbye object
[info] - should say goodbye
[info] Run completed in 377 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 2
[info] Suites: completed 2, aborted 1
[info] Tests: succeeded 2, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 SUITE ABORTED ***
[error] Error during tests:
[error]     example.AllSuites
[error] (Test / test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
```